# how to implement universal error handling exceptions in windows phone apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-7, exception, windows-phone-8

i am making application in windows phone 8 ,

i have many pages in it with many 100 buttons in it and the problem is that sometimes on button click event throws exceptions when message comes or when background music player is going .

so i don't want to add try catch  to every 100 button individually. i want to make try catch statement universal like that in asp.net global.aspx.
so what is the universal way to put exception handling and show message box when exception has occurred

Answer (score -2):

You can define the global function in App.xaml.cs. And you can use it on any page of application.

Comment: can you show me code sample for where to put and how to implement